# Null pointer exception while dequeing Queue in java

Tags: java, data-structures, queue, deque

My dequeue method :

```
public  T deQueue(){
        if(isempty()){
            System.out.println("Queue is empty, cant dequeue");
        }else if(front==rear){
            T value=queue[front];
            front=-1;
            rear=-1;
            return value;
        }else{
            T value=queue[front];
            front++;
            return value;
        }
        return null;    
    }
```

Here I'm returning as null in last line. Instead of null, what should I return?

Comment: what do you want to return?

Comment: I want to return the dequeued value. T- which is generic type

Comment: Instead of method I think you should more concentrate on call of method and add null check before using the result of method.

Comment: @TAsk I'm just trying to print those dequeued values :
System.out.println((T) newQueue.deQueue().toString());

Comment: you could use pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern

Answer (score 1):

You should add *null check* after calling the method to avoid null pointer exception.

```
Object object=newQueue.deQueue();
if(object!=null){
    System.out.println(object);
}
```

Comment: for each time displaying dequeue elements, i have to create as many objects?

Comment: No you can reuse the Object if you want to. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need not to specify return null at last. if - else if - else all cases are already handled.

Comment: Only half the truth: In the first `if` block, there's no `return`. So a final `return` is required. Also, I guess, the question is about what to return if there's no object of type `T` available.